# How do I return rows with a specific value last and order by name?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I want my query to return the rows of the table where a column (code) contains a specific value 3 or 4
then move bottom with order by customer

If I have a table something like this example:

```
       Name  Code  
      -------------
        Arun  1    
        Arun  2
        Arun  3
        Arun  4
        Babu  1
        Babu  3
        Raj   1
        Raj   2
        Ashok 1
        Ashok 2
```

And using that table I want to my query to return the rows which column (code) contain value 3 or 4  bottom, and then the order by name. Is this possible to do using only one query?

Expected output

```
       Name  Code 
      ------------
        Ashok 1
        Ashok 2
        Raj   1
        Raj   2
        Arun  1
        Arun  2
        Arun  3
        Arun  4
        Babu  1
        Babu  3
```

Comment: what will be your expected output ?

Comment: what you meant by `code (and third column date) but code = 3 or 4 it shows at the end of the list.`? show your _select_ ?

Comment: a guess : `select ... from atable where code in(3,4) order  by name,code,date`

Comment: If you want to have a view make a `view`, But this data in `table` will shown ordered by input time.

Comment: I want to shows all the record with order by name, code (but code 3, 4 show end of the list)

Comment: @user1731940 show the expected result

Comment: @user1731940  try `select * from atable order by code asc,name,date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a sub query in your `ORDER BY` clause which will allow for sorting by names which have 3/4 to be after other values:

```
SELECT atable.name, atable.code
FROM atable
ORDER BY (
  SELECT a1.code
  FROM atable a1
  WHERE a1.name = atable.name
  AND a1.code IN ( 3, 4 )
  LIMIT 1 ) DESC, atable.name, atable.code;
```

Comment: Please see the below query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011370/sql-extra-time-calculate-based-on-customer-plan-limit-and-sum-of-plan-used-past